# Adjust sidecaption that the caption placed in the margin starts at the top edge of the picture

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions, sidenotes

In my document I'm using a broad margin wherein the caption of figures should be placed. It works fine using the `sidenotes` package and `\sicecaption` command; espacially since the package edits the `figure*` environment that it spans through `\textwidth` and `\marginparwidth` and places the caption in the margin below.

For regular figures which only span `\textwidth` the caption is placed beside in the margin, BUT with a little setoff from the top edge of the figure. I want the caption to start right at the top edge of the figure.

I tried some tricks like adjusting `\abovecaptionskip` or `\marginnotevadjust`, since `sidenotes` uses `marginnotes` package for the captions. It is possible to move the caption upwards, but then also the captions of the `figure*` environment are moved upwards *into* the image.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
twoside
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[% Site-layout
%includeheadfoot%
]{geometry} % passt Seitengröße an (B5 usw.)
\geometry{%
    %includeheadfoot,
    inner=20mm,
    outer=60mm,
    top=15mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    marginparwidth=45mm,
    showframe,
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \sidecaption[Foto: Peter Paule]{A very long sidecaption describing not only the place, but the hole setting, the area, all the archaeological findings; and even every student worker who was digging in the dirt. A second sentence to test the heigth. A very long sidecaption describing not only the place, but the hole setting, the area, all the archaeological findings; and even every student worker who was digging in the dirt. A second sentence to test the heigth.}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\blindtext[3]

\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
    \sidecaption{A very long sidecaption describing not only the place, but the hole setting, the area, all the archaeological findings; and even every student worker who was digging in the dirt.}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
    \sidecaption{A very long sidecaption describing not only the place, but the hole setting, the area, all the archaeological findings; and even every student worker who was digging in the dirt.}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I intentionally used some longer captions, to see the effect of it.

How is it possible to move only the `sidecaption` of a regular `figure` environment to start at the top edge of the image and leave the sidecaption of wide figures (`figure*`) untouched?